# Posting image to twitter: out of memory error

Tags: android

I am developing an application that requires to post image to twitter, when I upload an image it shows out of memory error.
When I try a second time it is posted successfully.

```
 Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap Factory.decode File(path);
```

Comment: Check out : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: i don't want to crop it.

Comment: @vinodkumar if twitter does not give you any option to do a stream upload then you have no option but to scale it down. OOM happens when the image put into memory is bigger than the heap size of your device

Comment: if you are going to post it, you don't need to load it as bitmap. If you are going to display it, follow the link given by @HareshChhelana.

Answer (score 2):

Out of memory error occurs when bitmap is large. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html).
Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object).
And sometimes `largeheap=true` in manifest also solves this problem.